# Selecting limited values in the rows of a column (part 2)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with the following information:

```
Volkswagen Golf - 1.2 TSI Edition 5-drs (Climate control/Navigatie/Bluetooth)'
Volkswagen Golf - 1.5 TSI 130pk Life Business + Achteruitrijcamera + Stoelverwarming'
Volkswagen Golf Plus - 1.5 TSI 150pk DSG Highline Business R + LED Koplampen + Dynaudio'
```

1. I have left only numeric values in the rows

   ```
   df["Engine"] = df["Engine"].str.findall(r'[0-9]+.').str.join("")
   ```
2. Afterwards I have replaced some wrong values with a proper one

   ```
   df["Engine"] = df["Engine"].str.replace("5d","").str.replace("32 18","1.8")
   ```
3. Afterwards I have limited string to only first 3 values, since those mostly represent the Engine type

   ```
   df["Engine"] = df["Engine"].str[0:3]
   ```

As a result, I have the following output

```
['1.2' '1.5' '1.4' '1.6' '1.0' '2.0' '1.8' '1.1' '1.9' '1.7' '' '1.' '2.3' '1.3']
```

The issue is that I want to make `str.replace` both `'' '1.'`, however it does yield mistake, because as far as I understand `.str[0:3]` command does not make changes to the rows, but only display them in an abrupt way.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where is the engine value in the line do you want? There is a better way to obtain these values.

Comment: Hi Pramote. Obviously, I have limited knowledge of Pandas, therefore I utilize what I know so far. I want both values `'' '1.'` to be deleted/replaced.

Comment: If you know the location of the value, it would be easier to extract the value instead of extracting every number.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your statement, there is a typo: `"Enginge"` instead of `"Engine"`. Might want to check that as it can be that you are modifying the wrong column:

```
df["Engine"] = df["Enginge"].str.replace("5d","").str.replace("32 18","1.8").str.replace("5d","")
```

Secondly, I don't think the last replace is necessary as you already do the replace in the first place, and your second replace does not interfere with that.

Thridly, it seems like some of your filtering operations result in an empty string or a `'1.'` string to start off with. So I don't think the problem lies in the `[0:3]` syntax, but rather your string already starts off being `1.` before you do the indexing operation. Can you look at your data after the filtering and confirm that?

Comment: Hi mabergerx. Indeed, after filtering I have some value with `''` or `1.` values. I cannot replace them, because I immeadiately adjust other results as well, since they start with 1.

Comment: Right, but what would you want to do with these values ideally? Replace them with some other value? Which value? Or remove them?

Comment: Just remove them, since they comprise only a tiny part of my database.

Comment: Okay, then you may want to do it in steps, so first, after your initial filtering you can drop the unnecessary rows: `df["Engine"] = df[df["Engine"].str.len() > 2]` followed by `df.dropna(subset=["Engine"],inplace=True)`. Then you can proceed with the code you used: `df["Engine"].str[0:3]`

Answer (score 0):

A string in `pd.series` format is divided by `str.extract()` and extracted. The results are listed. Does this meet the intent of the question?

```
l = list(df['Engine'].str.extract('([0-9]\.[0-9])', expand=False))
l
['1.2', '1.5', '1.5']
```